# Converting Sting to xml and find the particular node in the xml

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, xml-parsing, jaxb

I have a confusion on this requirement how to do it.

I receive an xml as a string from the database and need to find the value of particular elements inside the xml string. Here, my thought was,

1- convert String to xml. 
2 - loop the xml using NodeList and DocumentBuilder (OR) Use JaxB. which one is the better option?

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely recommend JAXB instead of doing it by hand but if you're a bit masochistic it's doable by hand :3

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to use Regular Expressions or use Groovy:)

Comment: i want to use in java with spring boot non-web application

Comment: In fact it is doesn't matter. Please take a look at [this article](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm)